# Trouble breaking down a class and passing pointers

Tags: c++

I have working code in a single class that looks like this

```
Mesh* player_; // 
renderer_3d_->DrawSkinnedMesh(*player_, player_->bone_matrices());
```

seems straight forward, but I'm having trouble introducing another a vector of enemies going through classes, thanks to the pointers. 
I have two extra classes, enemy and manager. Enemy contains a SkinnedMeshInstance, and manager should worry about drawing it.

Manager

```
std::vector <Enemy> enemy_; 
enemy_.push_back(Enemy(*platform_)); // Initialise (platform is required by the default constructor, not relevant to the pointer issue)
rend->DrawSkinnedMesh(enemy_[0].getSkinnedMesh(), enemy_[0].getSkinnedMesh().bone_matrices()); //render, intellisense only accepts it this way
```

Enemy

```
Mesh* mesh_instance_; 
Mesh getSkinnedMesh() { return *mesh_instance_; };
```

What am I doing wrong here? Notice how rendering has changed how it's dereferenced. This way doesn't work as it throws some illegal access errors either at 'return *mesh_instance_;' or deeper in the framework itself, depending on how I try to change the communication. Might be simple for some but I feel like I tried everything possible.

Comment: Not much can be inferred from what you've given other than it looks like you may be dereferencing pointers without first pointing them at valid instances. Please edit your question to contain a [mcve].

Comment: among other things, intellisense is not a compiler and can have false positives.   Post actual compiler errors.

Comment: Does your `getSkinnedMesh()` function *know* that the pointer that it's holding is valid?  Is it a global variable that gets known-initialized as `NULL`?  (Categorically, I think that such a function should always be suspicious – *checking* for instance that the pointer's value is not null.)

Comment: @MikeRobinson you were right, I didn't initialise it as null. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I didn't inisialise my pointer as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Dunde, I'd like to beg the indulgence of the group to pass along a couple of "lessons painfully learned" about code such as this excerpt:

```
Mesh getSkinnedMesh() { return *mesh_instance_; };
```

*First,* of course, you know that you need to be absolutely-certain that variables such as `mesh_instance` really are global, and that they really are initialized to `NULL`.

Now, since you know that a call to this "accessor function" is going to take place each and every time someone needs to "get a skinned mesh," you should always take full advantage of this opportunity.  If you need to "automagically create a new object-instance," do so now.  And (IMHO), if there's something that you can do to verify that the pointer-value is "good" (using a `try` construct to detect a runtime-error that occurs while doing so), do it.  In this way, you now will be able to say: *"if* this method returns a value to you at all, then the value which it returns is good, because otherwise it's gonna blow up."

In practice, the hardest thing about any programming bug is – knowing that it exists, and where it is.  *"If you've got a traceback, you're home free."*